# jquery datepicker on windows phone not selecting the date

Tags: jquery-ui, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

When selecting the date in the standard JQuery datepicker on a Windows 7 phone i found that the date doesn't select for me and the field doesn't fill in the date. This feature works on all other tested devices including (of course the standard desktop) iTouch, iPad and Android. It almost acts like the dom object is not triggering when the datepicker is selected sometimes causing a text field behind the control to take focus. I did manage to get the timepicker (http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) work but not the datepicker.

Has anyone experienced this and found a fix? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

DateBox has a ton of options and it's built for jQM:

- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Answer (score 0):

try to use this line of code :

```
document.getElementById('container div of datepicker').innerHTML = document.getElementById('container div of datepicker').innerHTML
```

it seems like crazy and unbeliveable but it works with me